# Dynamically Created Element and event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to add event to dynamically created element.
it works fine for the first row, but needed to bind SplitSelectValue to the next generated row to.

```
$('#SelID_').change(function () {
SplitSelectValue($(this));
});

function SplitSelectValue () {
var data =$("#SelID_ option:selected").val();   
var arr = data.split('|');
$("#SelVala_").val(arr[0]);
$("#SelValb_").val(arr[1]);
$("#SelValc_").val(arr[2]);
}
```

See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3694/)

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3712/) with two different tables

Comment: id should be unique..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is,

1. Event-delegation
2. Attribute starts with selector
3. **Patience to fix the bugs**

Try,

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^="SelID_"]', function () {
    SplitSelectValue($(this));
});

function SplitSelectValue(obj) {
    var data = obj.find("option:selected").val();
    var arr = data.split('|');
    var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    tr.find("[id^='SelVala_']").val(arr[0]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelValb_']").val(arr[1]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelValc_']").val(arr[2]);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3697/)

Comment: it works fine for the row in the same table, but what if I create a row in another table [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3712/)

Answer (score 0):

use event - delegation

```
$(document).on('change', '#SelID_', function () {
SplitSelectValue($(this));
});
```

instead ID better use class selector ( ID must be unique at page, other way - generate id dynamicaly )

Comment: if you read the code in Jsfiddle, so you could see that ID is generated dynamicaly. So I think I need to use function(event) and counter.